How to fix this code to sort the full table?
I need help to fix this code to order by products by pretvat. When I run the code it sorts 6 products and at the 7th starts sorting again. What could be the problem?
I need the mysql query to join two tables to match the records and using user input to sort the tables.
<?php
require_once 'php/db_functions.php';

$orderby = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : '';
$minprice = isset($_GET['minprice']) ? $_GET['minprice'] : '';
$maxprice = isset($_GET['maxprice']) ? $_GET['maxprice'] : '';
$brand = isset($_GET['orderbybrand']) ? $_GET['orderbybrand'] : '';

$q = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '';

$sanitized_q = strip_tags($q);

$sanitized_q = '%' . $sanitized_q . '%';

// Define $conn variable with db_connect function from db_functions.php
$conn = db_connect();

// Prepare the statement to select products with the latest and lowest price
$query = "SELECT p.numeprodus, p.producator, p.data, pp.advertiser, pp.pretdiscount, pp.pretvat, p.imagineprodus
                        FROM prezentare_produse p
                        LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT a.numeprodus, a.advertiser, a.pretdiscount, a.pretvat, a.data, a.producator
                            FROM preturi_produse a
                            INNER JOIN (
                                SELECT numeprodus, MAX(data) AS latest_date
                                FROM preturi_produse
                                GROUP BY numeprodus
                            ) b ON a.numeprodus = b.numeprodus AND a.data = b.latest_date
                        ) pp ON p.numeprodus = pp.numeprodus
                        WHERE p.numeprodus LIKE ? AND pp.pretvat IS NOT NULL";

$query .= " GROUP BY pp.numeprodus";

switch ($orderby) {
    case 'alfabetic':
        $query .= ' ORDER BY p.numeprodus ASC';
        break;

    case 'crescator':
        $query .= ' ORDER BY pp.pretvat ASC';
        break;

    case 'descrescator':
        $query .= ' ORDER BY pp.pretvat DESC';
        break;

    default:
        $query .= ' ORDER BY p.data DESC';
        break;

}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("s", $sanitized_q);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

// Get the results
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Initialize an associative array to store unique producer names
$uniqueProducers = [];

// Display the results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;

        // Store unique producer names
        $uniqueProducers[$row['producator']] = $row['producator'];
    }
}

$conn->close();

?>


<div id="filterContainer">
                <form method="get" action="categorii.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($q); ?>">
                    <div>
                        <label for="orderby">Ordoneaza dupa:
                            <select name="orderby" id="orderby">
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Alerge o ordine</option>
                                <option value="alfabetic">Alfabetic</option>
                                <option value="crescator">Pret crescator</option>
                                <option value="descrescator">Pret descrescator</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="minprice">Pret minim:
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Introdu o suma minima aici" min="1" max="9999"
                                id="minprice" name="minprice">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="maxprice">Pret maxim:
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Introdu o suma maxima aici" min="1" max="9999"
                                id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="brand">Filtreaza dupa brand:
                            <select name="orderbybrand" id="brand">
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Alege un brand</option>
                                <?php foreach ($uniqueProducers as $product): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $product; ?>">
                                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?>
                                    </option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Cauta">
                </form>
            </div>
            <script src="js/filters.js" async></script>

            <div class='productsListing'>
                <div class='productsListingContent'>

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($data)) {
                        foreach ($data as $productDetails) {
                            $imageJsonObj = $productDetails['imagineprodus'];
                            $imageObj = json_decode($imageJsonObj);

                            echo "<div class='productsReview'>";
                            echo "<figure class='productsReviewImageContainer modalBoxTrigger' data-modalopen='modal-1'
                            onclick=\"showProduct('" . $productDetails['numeprodus'] . "')\">";
                            if (!empty($imageObj)) {
                                $firstImage = $imageObj[0];
                                echo "<img src='" . $firstImage . "'>";
                            }
                            echo "<figcaption class='productsReviewDetails'>" . $productDetails['numeprodus'];
                            if ($productDetails['pretdiscount'] == null) {
                                echo "<br>Pret: " . $productDetails['pretvat'] . " RON";
                            } else {
                                echo "<br>Pret: <s>" . $productDetails['pretvat'] . "</s> " . $productDetails['pretdiscount'] . " RON";
                            }

                            echo "</figcaption>";
                            echo "</figure>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        echo "<div id='seeMoreDiv'><button id='seeMoreBtn'>Vezi mai multe produse</button></div>";

                    } else {
                        echo "<div
                        style='text-align-last: center; margin: auto; width:100vw; height: 100vh; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-content: flex-start;'>
                        Nu s-au găsit rezultate pentru categoria: <b style='text-transform: capitalize;'>" .
                            htmlspecialchars($q) . "</b></div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

I was expecting to sort the full table from database.

FYI strip_tags isn't needed here

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. We can't see any sample data, any input test data, your current result, or your expected result. So it's hard to advise what might be wrong with your query on that basis, really.

I do wonder why you're using GROUP BY in the outer query without an aggregate function though.

Your question is is about returning sorted data from the database, there's no need to include all the PHP code

I agree with the existing comments. The question would be clearer if someone stripped the PHP code and left only the SQL. You might prefer ORDER BY to GROUP BY. Does "using user input to sort the tables" mean that the user specifies the sorting order and you might prefer to sort the data in the web application after it's returned from the database? Does " to join two tables to match the records' mean that you would prefer an INNER JOIN over a LEFT JOIN because an INNER JOIN will only return records with matches?
